# Getting right part of a decimal point in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I am doing a calculation which results in a decimal number. I want to get the right right part of the decimal. Is this possible in Oracle SQL?

Eg- 1/4 = 0.25

I need to get the 25 part using oracle sql.

```
select substr(TO_CHAR(ROUND((num1/num2)*24,2)), instr(TO_CHAR(ROUND((num1/num2),2)), '.') + 1) from dual
```

This sometimes work and sometimes don't is there another way in Oracle SQL to split the dot in decimal numbers and get the right part?

Comment: Gordon already asked you if the result must be a string, or a number. But there are more questions. If the input (arithmetic result) is 2.398 what is the desired output? 39? 398? or 4? or 40? With your attempt, you are rounding to two decimal places. If you round that number, the result is 2.4, so the only meaningful output after that is 4 or perhaps 40. Also: can the input be negative? What should be the output if the input is -1.25? Still 25?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`MOD()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions113.htm#SQLRF00668) function to return the part after the decimal point:

```
select mod(<whatever>, 1)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks this works but I need without the decimal point(only the number part right of the decimal point with out the decimal point)

Comment: Do you want the value as a number or a string?

Comment: Is that the only question - "number or string"? Is everything else about the problem clear to you? For example, if the input is negative: remainder(-1.2, 1) = -0.2; is that what the OP wants? Do you know the answer already?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to fetch digits anchored (`$`) to the right hand side of the resulting string (`to_char`):

```
SQL> select 1/4 value,
  2         regexp_substr(to_char(1/4), '\d+$') result
  3  from dual;

     VALUE RESULT
---------- ----------
       ,25 25

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks alot I tried many time using regexp your one works

Comment: @KushanPeiris Be careful with this as, when the value is an integer then this will not return `0` for the decimal part but will return the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT numerator,
       denominator,
       REPLACE( ABS(MOD( numerator/denominator, 1 )), '.' ) AS decimal_part
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( numerator, denominator ) AS
SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -9, 7 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NUMERATOR | DENOMINATOR | DECIMAL_PART                           
> --------: | ----------: | :--------------------------------------
>         1 |           4 | 25                                     
>         2 |           1 | 0                                      
>         2 |           3 | 666666666666666666666666666666666666667
>        -9 |           7 | 28571428571428571428571428571428571429
> ```

If you want the sign of the decimal part to be the same as the value then:

```sql
SELECT numerator,
       denominator,
       REPLACE( MOD( numerator/denominator, 1 ), '.' ) AS decimal_part
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NUMERATOR | DENOMINATOR |                            DECIMAL_PART
> --------: | ----------: | --------------------------------------:
>         1 |           4 |                                      25
>         2 |           1 |                                       0
>         2 |           3 | 666666666666666666666666666666666666667
>        -9 |           7 | -28571428571428571428571428571428571429
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=02ea39ed1160e93763303b2d4bc9c40d)*

Answer (score 0):

Using regex above may return the whole number in case of integers, i used the following to get the decimal part :

```sql
select substr(replace(to_char(185.250), '.', ','),
case
    when instr(replace(to_char(185.250), '.', ','), ',') = 0 then
        length(to_char(185.250))
    else
        instr(replace(to_char(185.250), '.', ','), ',') end +1)
from dual;
```